# Control automotive AC switch via TPS voltage

Tags: voltage, switches, relay, dc, automotive

The A/C compressor is engaged via a single wire that comes from the 'A/C' button on the dash board. I want the A/C button to disengage when the throttle is at 50%. The throttle position sensor (TPS) works based on voltage. 0.5-4.5V to be exact. 0.5V is idle (0%) and 4.5V is wide open throttle (100%).

What do I need to automatically disengage the A/C switch when the voltage exceeds (for example) 2.5V from the TPS?

The A/C compressor draws a lot of power from the crank and makes acceleration hard in a pinch.

Thank you.

Sorry automotive electronics are mostly very simple systems and this actually exceeds my current understanding of circuits and relays.

Comment: An opamp as a comparator, a pot and a 5V reference as the setting knob and a [TRIAC](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Power_Electronics#Triacs) (?) from the A/C switch to the A/C motor would probably do it for you. I am a bit worried that you might burn out the A/C motor or something else by constantly turning it on and off...

Comment: It should only engage a couple times per day. I would more than likely set it quite high, requiring flooring to disengage it. 

Someone asked me if this was possible and I swore it was. I was just unsure how to accomplish it. I simple lean over and press the button if I know I am going to need to accelerate quickly (I.E. on ramp).

Comment: It should work. However I am probably missing something automotive related and I don't want to suggest something that might damage the A/C motor.

Comment: a vacuum cutout switch is the simplest method if you can locate one these days. It was commoplace in the 60's

Comment: @EvangelosEm oil in the refrigerant provides both lubrication and cooling to the compressor in a car cooling system. I understand burning out is a problem in home HVACs; can you explain why it's a problem in vehicle ones too? perhaps I should make a question

Answer (score 1):

on some cars (scion tC) it's simple to remove the climate control unit from the dash. Behind it is a cable with 30 odd wires coming out of it, and a wiring diagram tells us which wire feeds (somewhere else) to (something else, presumably ECU) that handles actual compressor control. Installing a Reed relay in series with the correct wire, and wired "always on unless small comparator circuit triggers" could work. If you need a schematic I could edit one in.

the scion tC ECU is supposed to sense and disengage the AC clutch during heavy acceleration, but that doesn't happen.

Your question has inspired me to do this for myself. It might be good to implement a delay circuit so that the relay doesn't cycle with every shift (if yours is MT like mine). My original thought was to manage cruise control and AC state based on OBD2 data to keep AFR at the engine's preferred 'stoichiometric' 14.7:1, e.g. slower uphill and maybe AC off, faster downhill. At that point, it's not too much extra to add a laser distance detector to sense distance to the car ahead of you to automate cruise, which is what *really* would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

This will need some more engineering & testing, but this would be my first try at a solution. Hopefully others will give some feedback.

It may be possible to do this with a relay instead of a Mosfet, but the relays I looked at have quite a bit of histeresis (meaning if it turned off at 50% throttle, it might not turn back on until you go back below 5% throttle). If that's OK with you, then I can re-draw the circuit with a relay (it might be easier to get that working).

Anyway, the gist behind this circuit is that R1 is a potentiometer, which you can adjust until you like the turn on/off threshold. M1 is a p-channel mosfet, which should start to conduct when Vgs is below ~-1.1V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fs4fSb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: In the description, the OP writes there is one wire going to the clutch, so I think it's probably internally connected to ground, meaning you need to use a high-side switch.

Comment: You are right. This may not be workable without being able to insert the mosfet on the A/C return as shown.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're believing a bit too much marketing hype / car folklore, yeah the AC draws a little % of your HP when it's working hard but unless your engine is some tiny asthmatic little lump it should be unnoticeable, and if performance is THAT much of an issue then I'd point out that *proper* race cars don't have air-con, or heaters, or back seats, or carpets...

You'd probably gain more performance pumping your tyres up by 5psi.

If you *must* do this, there are a number of ways; using a simple comparator to fire a relay is one way. Using an n/o vacuum switch connected to the inlet is another, when you floor it, vacuum drops, switch drops out & disconnects AC. Or a microswitch / limit switch with a spring connected to the throttle arm (if you have one) or pedal arm if you don't.

Or go crazy and graft a centrifugal clutch onto the AC pulley. But don't add too much weight in the process or you'll cancel out all those big horsepower gains!

Comment: It's a 1.5L, 72 HP, motor in a late 80's vehicle. It's not a race car and the A/C draw on these motors is definitely noticeable. This isn't suppose to be a 'performance' thing.

Comment: I agree with Adam. On almost every vehicle I've driven, including my 280+ hp 350Z, the power loss due to the A/C is quite noticeable. It is less obvious with automatic transmissions. The Z will disconnect the A/C clutch at WOT just as the OP asks for, I suspect many other performance cars do the same. Adam, did you ever try out this circuit? Could be something lots of other auto tinkerers would be interested in.

Comment: my car has 160hp and it's still definitely noticeable; and yes, I must do this. Also, responses that tell the asker they're wrong for <pedantic reason> and suggest <unrelated solutions> are [annoying] not useful to the asker or the community. Finally, a centrifugal clutch would engage at RPM regardless of load. Maybe you should stop answering questions.

Comment: No need to be a dick about this: a 100hp car does not really notice the load from an AC compressor, I have driven such numerous times and it really doesn't impact. What MIGHT notice is a modern ECU which adjusts engine tune etc. based on everything from the AC switch to the volume of the stereo, especially if it's a very hot day and blasting the AC puts too much load on the cooling system (plus running the fans then adds more load on the alternator) and the ECU backs off on fuelling & ignition to reduce heat load. Many modern vehicles have aggressive/intrusive self-protection like this.